# Client application that can access SQL Server via OData or directly via an Entity Framework SQL Connection

Tags: entity-framework, odata, wcf-data-services

My application currently accesses SQL Server the "traditional" way - via EntityConnection on top of SqlClient. I would like to add the option of accessing SQL Server via a new OData service. Any ideas on the best way to do this? Is it possible to reuse the existing model-first EntityObject-derived classes? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The best way would be to follow this tutorial to create an OData service: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-v4/create-an-odata-v4-endpoint.

---

Update adding more details given the comment:

Although the link should be enough for answering the question, I can also elaborate on the end-to-end scenario a little bit.

Now the premium experience of creating an OData V4 service out of an SQL Server DB is to use the ASP.NET Web API 2.2 for OData V4. With the help of the code-first aspect of entity framework you can create an OData V4 service that supports pagination, queries, and CRUD operations in a very reasonable time (about 10 minutes for every table in your database).

As soon as the service is created, various client libraries that supports consuming V4 services can be at your service. The premium experience on the .NET platform is the [OData v4 Client Code Generator](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9b786c0e-79d1-4a50-89a5-125e57475937).

If your consumer is a non-developer, Power Query can help you import the data from the OData service. Their support for V4 services will come early next year according to [this](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2169958f-9e2a-4fc2-a844-c0dce4c17a19/support-of-odata-v40?forum=powerquery), but Excel and Power Pivot already natively support consuming V1-3 services. For creating a V1-3 service, the tutorial next to the one I gave at first would help.